# Combine elseifs

Tags: php, if-statement

It might be a stupid question but I am failing to combine multiple `elseif`. I'm sure there must be smarter way. Do you have an idea?

```
<?php
$level_ids = leaky_paywall_subscriber_current_level_ids();

if (!empty($level_ids)) {
    if (in_array(2, $level_ids)) {
        echo 'DO THIS';
    } elseif (in_array(3, $level_ids)) {
        echo 'DO THIS';
    } elseif (in_array(4, $level_ids)) {
        echo 'DO THIS';
    } elseif (in_array(6, $level_ids)) {
        echo 'DO THIS';
    } elseif (in_array(7, $level_ids)) {
        echo 'DO THIS';
    } elseif (in_array(9, $level_ids)) {
        echo 'DO THIS';
    } elseif (in_array(10, $level_ids)) {
        echo 'DO THIS';
    } else {
        echo 'DO THAT';
    }
}
```

I tried to combine that much smarter but it doesn't work.

Thank you so much for helping put!

Comment: What if multiple of these statements are true? Your current code will only ever run `DO THIS` for the first match

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
if ([] === array_intersect([ 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10 ], leaky_paywall_subscriber_current_level_ids())) {
  echo 'DO THAT';
} else {
  echo 'DO THIS';
}
```

Comment: As I've been repeating to you lately, please stop posting code-only answers on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with the way you wrote it. I would have formatted the code slightly differently according to the [One True Brace Style](https://wiki.c2.com/?OneTrueBraceStyle), but that's because I've been around forever:

```
if (...) {
  echo 'DO THIS';
} elseif (...) {
  echo 'DO THIS';
} else {
  echo 'DO THAT';
}
```